# In Vue.js, how can I emit multiple value from child to parent while parent's v-on pass another parameter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is a code example.

```js
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  template: '<button v-on:click="emit_event">button</button>',
  methods: {
    emit_event: function () {
      this.$emit('change', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3')  // Here I emit multiple value
    }
  },
})
new Vue({
  el: '#parent',
  data: {
    args: ""
  },
  methods: {
    change: function (...args) {
      this.args = args
      console.log(args)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.common.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  {{ args }} <br />
  <button-counter v-on:change="change(1234, $event)"></button-counter>
</div>
```

From the parent component, I want to get parameter pass by change() (in this example, 1234), but also every value emitted by child component.
I try to use $event to catch the values child emit, however $event is only set up to the first value child emit (int this example, 'v1')

Is there any way to do that? I know I can emit an array to catch multiple value. But some library just emit multiple value.

This is the codepen for above example.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmLEqX?editors=1011

Comment: `some library just emit multiple value` - collect these values into an array or object, and pass it as the event. Mulpitle values are not supported here.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Define a handler that accepts the multiple parameters from the event and passes them along to the change method in addition to your static parameter.

```
<button-counter v-on:change="(...args)=>this.change(1234,...args)"></button-counter>
```

Alternatively

```
<button-counter v-on:change="(...args)=>this.change([1234,...args])"></button-counter>
```

And change your method to

```
change: function (args) {
  this.args = args
  console.log(args)
}
```

Comment: @Craig Seems trivial to convert the answer to a regular function syntax. I don't see the point in doing so. If you're writing code in an environment that doesn't support arrow functions, the spread syntax is unlikely to work either. In any case, you're free to provide your own answer without an arrow function.

Answer (score 33):

You can use destructuring syntax

```
this.$emit('change', { x:'v1', y:'v2', z: 'v3' })
```

And you can access these values like so

```
<button-counter @change="change"></button-counter>

methods: { change({x, y, z}) { .... } }
```

Comment: So elegant! thanks! `this.$emit('blur', { e, $ref: this });` --> `handlerOnBlur({ e, $ref }) {}`

Answer (score 10):

I would do this:

```
<button-counter v-on:change="change(1, ...arguments)">
```